# multiple openpyxl xlsx workbooks into one .zip file for download

Tags: django, openpyxl, zip

I am trying to get some xlsx files from a form, i load them using openpyxl and do some data processing.. and finally i need to download all processed xlsx files zipped to the user.

here is an example of what i did so far

```
if form.is_valid():

    s = StringIO.StringIO()
    zf = zipfile.ZipFile(s, mode="w")

    for xlsx in request.FILES.getlist('xlsxs'):

        element_column = "G"
        element_row = 16

        massar_column = "C"
        massar_row_start = 18

        loop = column_index_from_string(element_column)
        while (loop <= ws.max_column):
            for i in range(massar_row_start, ws.max_row+1):
                # ...
                ws["%s%s" % (element_column,i)] = 0
                # ...

            loop+=2
            element_column = get_column_letter(loop)

        buf = save_virtual_workbook(wb)
        zf.write(buf) # or zf.write(wb)

    zf.close()
    response = HttpResponse(s.getvalue(), content_type="application/x-zip-compressed")
    response['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=notes.zip"
    return response
```

I get the error

```
TypeError at My_view
stat() argument 1 must be encoded string without null bytes, not str
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer.

Comment: When reporting errors, you should give the full stack trace - it will tell you and us where the actual error is. You should also include what Python version, and what other libraries (Django?) and there versions.

Comment: @spookylukey the error is in the line 'zf.write(buf)' i am using django 1.10 with python 2.7.12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`save_virtual_workbook` returns a bytestream - [source](https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/src/f79ce0a7546076be434ee1d41c2ac52e1e738f79/openpyxl/writer/excel.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#excel.py-273).

You are passing this value to [ZipFile.write](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.write) which is expecting a filename.

I think you should be using [ZipFile.writestr](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.writestr), and you need to provide a filename that will be used inside the archive. I'm not sure how you are getting the error message you see, but this is the first mistake I can see.

Comment: zf.writestr(xlsx.name, buf) fixes the problem. thanks